# ngrx update a value in object

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am trying to update a single value inside an object. I know that I cannot mutate an object using redux pattern. But I cannot figure out how to solve this simple problem:

```
const updateMonthForecast = (monthParam: string, dayWorked: number) => {
    const copyState = [...initialState];

    copyState.find((month) => month.month === monthParam).dayWorked = dayWorked;

    return [...copyState];
}
```

here is the initialState which is a simple array with objects:

```
const initialState = [
    {
        month: "january",
        dayWork: 22,
        dayWorked: 0,
        CA: 0
    },
    {
        month: "februrary",
        dayWork: 20,
        dayWorked: 0,
        CA: 0
    },
]
```

EDIT: here the message error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'dayWorked' of object '[object Object]'
```

Comment: what's the problem? if I run the above code it properly modify the correct object. Also, you can just return copyState since you are already creating a new Array on the first statement of your fn

Comment: I updated my post with the error message

Comment: it is possible that the above fn is called with a `monthparam` not corresponding to any of the available obj. In that case you would get that error.
Consider assigning the value returned by the find to a variable, and check if it exist before modifying its dayworked prop.

Comment: You can use immer to make this easier - https://github.com/timdeschryver/ngrx-immer

Answer (score 0):

```
const updateMonthForecast = (monthParam: string, dayWorked: number) => {
  const copyState = [...initialState];

  const resultState = copyState.map(monthItem => {
    let result;
    if (monthItem.month === monthParam) {
      result = {...monthItem, dayWorked: dayWorked}
    }
    else 
    {
      result = monthItem;
    }
    return result;
  });
  
  return resultState;
}
```